# How to create simple graphical editor?

Tags: javascript

I started learning javascript recently. Now I have a task... And it seems be more than I can.

I need to build a graphical editor, which can add a rectangle on an image, which can be modified (move borders).

What I got until now, is getXY position at start, and the end, id of img... and thats it.

```
<html>
<head>

<script type="text/javascript">
window.onload = init;
function init() {
  if (window.Event) {
    document.captureEvents(Event.MOUSEMOVE);
  }
  document.onclick = getXY;
}


function getXY(e) {
  x = (window.Event) ? e.pageX : event.clientX;
  y = (window.Event) ? e.pageY : event.clientY;

    document.getElementById(document.getElementById('position1').value === '' ? 'position1' : 'position2').value = x+":"+y;

}

function getID(oObject) 
{
    var id = oObject.id;
    document.position.gei.value = id;

}

function markIt()
{
var mark = document.createElement('div');
    mark.id = 'mark';
    mark.style.background = '#fff';
    document.getElementById('wrapper').appendChild('mark');
}

</script>

</head>
<body>
<div id="kontener">
<form name="position">
    <input name="position1" id="position1" type="text" /><input name="position2" id="position2" type="text" /><input name="gei" type="text" id="getElementId" />
    </form>
<div id="wrapper"><img src="ferrari_01.jpg" width="1000" height="650" ismap="ismap" id="ferrari" onclick="getID(this);markIt(mark);"/></div>
<div id="wrapper"><img src="peugeot.jpg" width="100" height="100" id="peugeot" onclick="getID(this);"/></div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: can you show this with jsfiddle?

Comment: You can't append a `div` to an `img`, since [`img`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/Img) can't have any content. You need to use a wrapper `div` around the image, and append your `div` with "moving borders"  to the wrapper.

Comment: I`ve changed it, so now is wrapper around any img file. But I still have no div to create rectangle. And for jsfiddle [http://jsfiddle.net/Rs9aW/] link here

Comment: The provided fiddle link seems to be broken (there's an axtra `]` in the address). Please take a look at your console, you'll find errors...

Comment: Strange... but I have new one: http://jsfiddle.net/s45Pa/